# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when assigning an Objective-C pointer to a member of a C struct

Tags: c, objective-c, struct, malloc

Sometimes but not always I'm getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash assigning an `NSMutableDictionary` to a struct. I'm obviously doing something wrong but I have no idea what.

```
typedef struct {
    
    ...
    NSMutableDictionary* headers;
    ...
    
} custom_data_t;

...

- (void)method {

    custom_data_t* customData = malloc(sizeof(custom_data_t));
    customData->headers = [NSMutableDictionary new]; // <- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

}
```

Comment: @GP89 See [WWDC 2018 What's New in LLVM](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/409/?time=48) from "But there is one place we have to put in a little bit of extra work to support structures with ARC object pointer fields and that place is heap."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, avoid allocating any C structure which has pointers to Objective-C objects with `malloc`. It tends to be a problem, because ARC tries to release whatever is set to an ARC-managed pointer when it's not `nil` upon assigning new values (and since `malloc` does not zero member variables of the structure object, the pointers may point to some garbage, which ARC will try to release. This is where `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error happens). Instead you should use `calloc` which ensures that all member variables are zero-initialised:

```
custom_data_t* customData = calloc(1, sizeof(custom_data_t));
```

Second, while using `calloc` you should be advised that ARC cannot properly release member variables (because it doesn't know exact length of the pointer), so before freeing a C structure memory, you also need to nullify all its ARC managed pointers:

```objc
customData->headers = [NSMutableDictionary new];
// .. some time later ..
customData->headers = nil;
free(customData);
```